# Android AnimationDrawable сжатие кадров

Tags: android, анимация, bitmap, drawbitmap

Есть серия кадров в png.
Делаю анимацию с помощью AnimationDrawable.

Сами кадры не очень много весят, но в ОЗУ достаточно плачевная ситуация.
Хотел сжать каждый кадр использовав -  RGB 565

Но не могу сообразить как это сделать.

**UPD:**

Пример как делаю:

```
animSearch.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_search);
mAnimationDrawable2 = (AnimationDrawable) animSearch.getDrawable();
mAnimationDrawable2.start();
```

Сам anim_search:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim1_00001" android:duration="250" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim1_00002" android:duration="125" />
    .....
</animation-list>
```

Пробовал делать так:

```
private void startFrameAnimation() {

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anim1_00001, o);
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anim1_00002, o);
        Bitmap bitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anim1_00003, o);

....

        mAnimationDrawable2 = new AnimationDrawable();

        mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap1), 250);
        mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap2), 125);
        mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap3), 125);

.....

        mAnimationDrawable2.setOneShot(false);

        animSearch.setBackground(mAnimationDrawable2);

        if (!mAnimationDrawable2.isRunning()) {
            mAnimationDrawable2.setVisible(true, true);
            mAnimationDrawable2.start();
        }
}
```

Но не особо то помогло, 37 кадров, каждый весит по 30 кб. размером 340 на 240 примерно, занимает в памяти около 120 мегабайт. Кадры не имеют альфаканал.

Answer (score 1):

Тяжело помочь решить какую либо проблему, не видя кода. Старайтесь прикреплять хотя бы то что есть, чтобы людям было более ясно в каком конкретно моменте у вас затруднения.

Исходя из информации которую вы предоставили в вопросе вот код который переделывает ARGB_8888 в RGB_565.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

setContentView(R.layout.high_scores);
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
BitmapDrawable highScoresBg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.achievements, opts);
findViewById(R.id.high_scores_root).setBackgroundDrawable(highScoresBg);
```